# Are separable verbs treated differently in the imperative?

Tags: imperative, separable-verb

Here: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/Imperative/Imperativ.html

there's a photograph of a sign saying:

> Nehmen Sie bitte Ihren Müll mit nach Hause

Now my understanding is that the verb there is "mitnehmen", and the sentence should read:

> Nehmen Sie bitte Ihren Müll nach Hause mit

Or are there special rules with the imperative?

Comment: "nach Hause" ist ein predikativer Adjunkt. Du kannst es also fallen lassen, ohne die Information zu ändern. Außerdem gehört es zum Prädikativ, "ergänzt" sozusagen das Verb. Sogesehen ist das Verb "mit nach mause nehmen".

Comment: Also ist mein Beispiel mit dem "mit" am Ende ungrammatisch?

Comment: Keine Ahnung ^^ Müsste ich den Satz auseinander plücken und drüber nachdenken. Zu müde dafür. Es kommt drauf an, ob es nur eine Präpositionalphrase ist oder ein "echtes" Satzglied.

Comment: was ich damit meine ist, in "der blaue schöne Hund" kannst du den Gesamtausdruck verschieben, aber "blaue schöne"( was eine Adjektivphrase ist) nicht. "blaue schöne der hund" ist falsch.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind möglich. Das liegt daran, dass `mit nach Hause nehmen` eine fest Phrase und somit nahezu schon ein eigenständiges ist. Als solche wird der Imperativ als `Nehmen Sie bitte Ihren Müll mit nach Hause!`. Natürlich kann man den Satz auch aus dem eigentlichen Prädikat `mitnehmen` und dem Adjunkt `nach Hause` konstruieren. Dann wird der Imperativ als `Nehmen sie bitte ihren Mülll nach Hause mit!`

Comment: Very good question. For a native speaker like me, such questions  highlite difficulties of the language I did not even dream they would exist.

Comment: Another example: `Fahren Sie nach Stuttgart zurück!` vs. `Fahren Sie zurück nach Stuttgart!` - I think that kills @Toscho's argument, since `zurück nach Stuttgart fahren` is certainly not a fixed phrase. And yet, both sentences are possible.

Comment: @Ingo Aber er hat recht, dass man beides sagen kann. Sieht man, wenn man den Satz ganz ändert: "Nach Hause werden wir den Müll mitnehmen." Das ist absolut legitim, der Betonung wegen.

Comment: @Em1 Ja, freilich hat er Recht, und `mit nach Hause nehmen` ist in der Tat eine feste Phrase. Aber wenn A und B wahr sind, kann "A wegen B" trotzdem falsch sein, bzw. in unserem Fall nicht erklären, warum es bei anderen Sätzen auch geht.

Comment: @Ingo Die Präpositionalphrase ist ein eigenständiges Satzglied. Zu dem Entschluss bin ich inzw. gekommen. Damit kannst du es im Satz verschieben. Aber nur dort hin natürlich, wo es syntaktisch erlaubt ist.

Comment: @Ingo `nach [Ort] zurückfahren` würde ich auch als feste Phrase ansehen. Aber es kann sein, dass du Recht hast. Möglicherweise müssen nur die Komplemente zwischen den beiden Verbteilen stehen.

Answer (score 4):

Putting things outside of the verbal bracket is called `Ausklammerung.` A final verbal element can be a separable prefix, infinitive, or participle in main clause statements, questions and commands and in subordinate clauses it's the finite verb.

> Ich will nicht mitmachen - here *will* and *mitmachen* for brackets around most of the sentence
>
> Ich nehme an, dass du nicht mitmachen willst. - here *nehme* and *an* form a bracket in their respective clause, and *willst* as the final element ends the bracket in its clause.

*Ausklammerung* is preferable/acceptable...

1) With subordinate clauses: these are not usually enclosed in a verbal bracket, and when they are it can become rather unwieldy

> Das „Vorsicht-Glatteis!“-Verkehrszeichen, das letzte Nacht, die Forstbildung, was für den Autofahrer, der etwas getrunken und ein Auto gefahren, das abgefahrene Reifen hat, hat, erhöhte Gefahren mit sich bright, brachte, total beschädigt wurde, wird mir nicht aufgestellt.

You can see this example is hyperbolic, but it shows how putting whole sentences into your sentences, can get insane.

> Ich konnte den Gedanken nicht loswerden, **dass wir ihn betrogen hatten**
>
> Ich konnte den Gedanken, **dass wir ihn betrogen hatten**, nicht loswerden.

Nowadays the former example is used more often than the latter.

Oftentimes, to avoid putting entire sentences into other sentences through relative clauses, the relative clause can be moved away from the noun it modifies

> Und die dürfte man eine Zeitung verbieten, **die sich wiederholt und nachhaltig für die Wahl der staatstragenden Partei eingesetzt hat**? (*Spiegel*)
>
> Und die dürfte man eine Zeitung, **die sich wiederholt und nachhaltig für die Wahl der staatstragenden Partei eingesetzt hat**, verbieten?

You see closing your clauses in with other sentences can produce undesirable effects which is why *Ausklammerung* is preferred here.

2) Infinitive clauses: this generally will not get enclosed

> Sie haben beschlossen, nach Hause zu gehen

instead of

> Sie haben, nach Hause zu gehen, beschlossen.

3) Comparative phrases introduced by *als* or *wie*

> Gestern haben wir einen besseren Film gesehen, als diesen.

However, it is not unusual to enclose these phrases

> Gestern haben wir einen besseren Film als diesen gesehen.

In longer sentences it is especially more common to include the comparative phrase in the verbal bracket

> da die Orangen und Zitronen von den Kindern wie Schneebälle über die Gartenmauern geworfen wurden (*Andres*)

3) Other elements can be placed outside the verbal bracket for 3 main reasons

3.1) emphasis on the element places last

> Du hebst das auf **bis nach dem Abendessen** (*Baum*)

3.2) as an afterthought

> Ich habe Sie doch heute gesehen **in der Stadt**

3.3) to not overstretch the verbal bracket

> Seitdem Rodrigue seine Chronik begonnen hatte, freute er sich darauf, sie zu beschließen **mit der Darstellung der Regierung dieses seines lieben Schülers und Beichtkindes.**

The following elements are commonly places outside the verbal bracket

a) adverbials which have the form of prepositional phrases

> Hallo, ich rufe an **aus London** (*Telecommunication advertisement*)
>
> Vieles hatte Glum schon gesehen **auf seinem Weg von seiner Heimat bis über den Rhein hinweg (*Böll*)

This is more common in speech than writing, but does appear in writing sometimes especially if it would make the sentence unreasonably lengthy

> Von hier aus konnte man noch wenig sehen *von der kleinen Stadt*, die am anderen Ufer im Nebel lag

To have this relative clause in the middle of a sentence could be unwieldy and it could be unclear to the reader/listener if you left the prepositional phrase in the sentence and kept the relative clause at the end

b) Prepositional objects are <strike>the only verbal complement to be regularly excluded in standard German</strike> sometimes excluded, but this is not standard German

> Du sollstest dich nicht zu sehr freuen auf diese Entwicklung

However, not all prepositional objects can be used like this; for example:

> Ich habe vor dem Bahnhof gewartet auf meine Freundin

is **not** correct. There aren't really established rules about what can and what cannot be excluded.

c) Other verb complements are sometimes excluded in colloquial German generally not in standard German (pronouns never get excluded, but nouns can be)

> <strike>Gestern hat er gesehen Max und Julia</strike>

d) Adverbs: simple adverbs are sometimes excluded in colloquial German but generally not in
formal or written German

> Bei uns hat das Fußballspiel Spaß gemacht heute.
>
> Hat es dir gefallen dort?
>
> Sollen wir leise reden hier?

Source: Durrell, Martin, and A. E. Hammer. Hammer's German grammar and usage. 5th ed. London: Hodder Education, 2011. Print.

Comment: Excellent answer, that incidentally also clears up some other doubts that I had. Thanks!

Comment: Nice Answer. I have to disagree on some things though: prepositional objects (3.3 b)) are not  "regulary excluded". As a native speaker I must object to this. Also you example on Max und Julia (3.3 c)) is not correct. And last but not least I am unable to wrap my head around your Fußball-Sentence (3.3 d))...

Comment: I got a lot of my information from a book, so thank you for looking over it because I can't verify the veracity of it all (not being a native speaker and all)! I'll strike that stuff out. Danke! (ps: I just realized I forgot the word Spaß in 3.3d which is why it didn't make sense)

Comment: In the section number 1) you wrote: "das letzte Nacht", but it should be "die letzte Nacht".