# Trennbare Verbpräfixe inmitten des Satzes

Tags: word-order, separable-verb

Wird ein trennbares Verb in einem Satz verwendet, so steht ja bekanntlich das abgetrennte Präfix **am Ende** des Satzes, z.B.:

- weggehen: Wir *gehen* heute Abend zusammen *weg*.
- vorziehen: Er *zieht* die Jacke der Hose *vor*.

etc.

Nun gibt es aber auch seltene Fälle, in denen es sich natürlicher (oder zumindest nicht falsch) anhört, das Präfix in die Mitte des Satzes zu stellen:

- mitkommen: *Kommst* du *mit* ins Kino? statt *Kommst* du ins Kino *mit*?
- fortgehen: Ich *gehe* *fort* von hier! statt Ich *gehe* von hier *fort*!

Handelt es sich dabei um rein umgangssprachliche Abwandlungen oder steckt ein System dahinter?

Comment: Ähnlich zu https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23470/is-putting-an-adverbial-after-the-non-finite-verb-okay (englisch). In beiden Fällen geht es um Satzteile im _Nachfeld_, d.h. hinter der Verbklammer, die hier bis zum abgetrennten Präfix reicht und in der anderen Frage bis zum Infinitiv.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15159/h%C3%A4tte-sie-mehr-zeit-so-k%C3%A4me-sie-mit-zur-party-position-of-mit/15162#15162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Verhältnis von Verb und Präposition gibt es drei Stufen, aber auch dazwischen sind die Übergänge fließend. Dadurch ist es auch möglich, dass eine Verb-Präposition-Kombination allmählich die Klasse wechselt:

1. Verb steht für sich und Präposition steht für sich. Die beiden werden aber evt. häufig zusammen gebraucht, weil sie inhaltlich gut zusammenpassen.
2. Trennbares Verb. In den infiniten Verbformen wird die Präposition dem Verb vorangestellt und mit diesem zusammengeschrieben. (Letzteres ist aber nur ein Zufall unserer Rechtschreibung.) Was die Wortstellung betrifft, gehört das Verb zum Prädikat.
3. Präfix-Verb. Die Präposition steht immer vor dem Verb.

Durch die Existenz des Verbs *mitkommen* (2) ist das Verb *kommen* ja nicht verschwunden, und es ist insbesondere auch nicht verboten, es ganz normal in Verbindung mit der Präposition *mit* zu benutzen (1). Auch das kann man dem fließenden Übergang zwischen (1) und (2) zurechnen.